# fillter a list in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of list, I want to separate the elements after/before/between a specified string in python.

Example:

**After a specified string:**

```
input1 : [['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccc', 'specified string', 'ddddd', 'eeeeee', 'ffffff']]

output1 : ddddd, eeeeee, ffffff
```

**Between a specified string:**

```
input2 : [['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccc', 'specified string1', 'ddddd', 'eeeeee', 'ffffff', 'specified string2', 'qqqq', 'wwww', 'sssss']]

output2 : ddddd, eeeeee, ffffff
```

**Before a specified string:**

```
input3 : [['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccc', 'specified string', 'ddddd', 'eeeeee', 'ffffff']]

output3 : aaaaa, bbbbb, cccc
```

Comment: Can you please share with us your attempts? Currently it just looks like you're asking us to do your work for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functions [`itertool.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and [`itertool.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile). I think it could be a bit better than use `index` in terms of performance (at least if you need to get list between 2 strings):

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile, takewhile
>>> input1 = [['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccc', 'specified string', 'ddddd', 'eeeeee', 'ffffff']]
>>> input2 = [['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccc', 'specified string1', 'ddddd', 'eeeeee', 'ffffff', 'specified string2', 'qqqq', 'wwww', 'sssss']]
>>> input3 = [['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccc', 'specified string', 'ddddd', 'eeeeee', 'ffffff']]
>>> f = lambda x: x <> 'specified string'
>>> f1 = lambda x: x <> 'specified string1'
>>> f2 = lambda x: x <> 'specified string2'
>>>
>>> list(dropwhile(f, input1[0]))[1:]
['ddddd', 'eeeeee', 'ffffff']
>>> list(takewhile(f2, dropwhile(f1, input2[0])))[1:]
['ddddd', 'eeeeee', 'ffffff']
>>> list(takewhile(f, input3[0]))
['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccc']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can access the list within the list by simply:

```
lst = list_of_list[0]
```

Now you want to search for "specified string". You can:

```
lst.index('specified string')
```

Which will return the index on which the string appears. Finally, you can use slicing to get the sublist you want.

Try to do this and if you'll have problems, post it here and we'll help you.

Comment: probably better names to use than list

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the indexes of your `specified string`:

```
boundaries = [index for index, item in input.items() if item == specified_string]
```

And then you can easily extract the parts you need:

```
first = input[:boundaries[0]-1] # until the first occurrence
middle = input[boundaries[0]+1:boundaries[1]-1] # between the first and the second
last = input[boundaries[0]+1:] # from the last to the end
```